# Calling a JS script in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello there I have this code and I want to display active links in purple. I have that in a js file however, does not seem to work as expected. I am not sure where exactly I am doing wrong. Everything else is working properly but when you clink a link it fails to highlight to purple as is in the css. I have provided the necessary code only, Anyone?

**html**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">   <script src="color.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <ul class="navigation-menu">
        <li><a href='start.php'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='pay.php'>C2B Payments</a> </li>
        <li><a href='sms.php'>C2B SMS</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>B2C Payments</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="getbtc.php"> B2C Payments</a></li>
            <li><a href="payment.php"> Make Payments</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='bsms.php'>B2C SMS</a></li>
        <li><a href='index.php'>Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**css (site.css)**

```css
.navigation-menu li.active a {
  background-color: purple;
  color:#fff;
}
.navigation-menu li ul {
  display: none;
}

.navigation-menu li a:hover{
  background-color:black;
  color: white;
}
.navigation-menu li a.active {
  background-color: purple;
  color:#fff;
}
```

**javascript (color.js)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li a').click(function(){
    $('li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you linked everything? The JS and jQuery?

Comment: `<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">`  for CSS and   `<script src="color.js"></script> ` for JS are the links in HTML file above

Comment: Any errors in the `console`?

Comment: The reason why it happening is because the link takes you to a different page which makes the CSS and jQuery start all over again

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea how to link the jquery. @AndrewL.

Comment: Download the jQuery file or link through a cdn and have a script tag with the src leading to the file *before* using it

Comment: By the way, have you considered using the CSS `:active` pseudo-class?

Comment: No. Let me have a look at it. May be it helps as I honestly don't get much about jq.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to highlight active links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025517/how-to-highlight-active-links)

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems.

First, you haven't included [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) on the page, so when the JS runs, it throws an error because `$` isn't defined.

If you were to fix then this would be the order of events:

1. The link is clicked
2. The JavaScript starts running
3. The JavaScript modifies the DOM of the page
4. The JavaScript finishes
5. The browser follows the link
6. The page with the modified DOM is discarded
7. A new page is loaded

… and the new page hasn't been modified by the JavaScript.

Put the `active` class in the HTML of the new page.

Comment: `Put the active class in the HTML of the new page` but this is a totally different code because you don't know who the link you clicked on it. So you try to figure it out by the `location.href` for example (`$('[href=' + location.href + ']')`).

Comment: (https://jsfiddle.net/rv6adud7/6/) worked here but honestly don't what you mean. @MoshFeu

Comment: @MoshFeu — I said "in the HTML". You don't need to figure it out with JavaScript.

Comment: @Quentin if the html file is static. In the **most** of the cases that is not the situation.. But it's not relevant to the question..

Comment: @Bob — That's the same URL. It has CSS. It has JS. Unlike the code in your question it has jQuery. It has no HTML.

Comment: @MoshFeu — Even if the HTML is dynamically generated, you can still modify which element has the class attribute on it when you generate it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to check the page url and match href in the element and add class active to respective element

You have to include jQuery Lib

Replace test.html page2.html by the name of page u have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pageURL = $(location).attr('href'),
        pageName= [ /test.html/, /page2.html/, /page3.html/],
        links = $('a'),
        LinksToActive;

    for( var i=0; i < $(pageName).size(); i++){
            for( var j=0; j < $(links).size(); j++){
                var str = $(links[j]).attr('href');
                if( 'str:contains(pageName[i])' ){
                    LinksToActive = $(links[j]);
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    continue
                }
            }
    }
    $(LinksToActive).addClass('active');

    });
```

Change/ Add page name in pageName variable nad this script just before closing of body tag